# Why does this mysql query fail to return certain rows depending on their value

Tags: mysql, sqlfiddle

I was testing a query in sqlfiddle and noticed something strange:

If you take a look at this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c63eb/1) it's working correctly, or I guess it behaves as expected.

But [this one](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1ac7f/1) is doing something completely different.

I've noticed that depending on the values of the timestamp the query works or it doesn't, is this something unique to sqlfiddle or is it a sqllite thing? What is going on?

*** EDIT ***

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM a
join b
on a.id = b.id
group by a.id
having b.tstamp = max(b.tstamp)
```

Comment: Pasting links to SQL Fiddle is useful as additional information, but you should always paste the query in question here as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `HAVING` clause is to late, It runs *after* the grouping, there are no multiple b records per row anymore, b contains an *arbitrary* record from the table (usually the first match in the row order, but this should *not* be relied upon), `HAVING b.something = MAX(b.something)` is the same as saying `HAVING 1 = MAX(1);`, or `1=1`, or in other words: is always true for that random record of the group.

Your desired result could be done with a self join or subqueries, I like the self join as MySQL performs quite well with it:

```
SELECT * 
FROM a
JOIN b b1
   ON b1.id = a.id
LEFT JOIN b b2
   ON b2.id = a.id
   AND b2.tstamp > b1.tstamp
WHERE b2.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: That makes sense, so then this query is useless, because it's not possible to insert an `ORDER BY b.tstamp DESC` before the `GROUP BY a.id` correct?

Comment: Nope, it isn't. You can go the subquery route, or use the `JOIN` solution I just added in. Mind you: this will return 2 (or more) records for a if there are b's with the _exact_ same `tstamp`, which is usually desirable but may not be what you want, in which case you can `GROUP BY a .id` again, or possibly, if you for instance want the highest `b.id` in case of a tie, alter `AND b2.timestamp > b1.timestamp` to `AND (b2.tstamp > b1.tstamp OR (b2.tstamp = b1.tstamp AND b2.id > b1.id))`

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't trust that query to run correctly in the first place.

My version would be:

```
SELECT a.id AS id, MAX(b.tstamp) AS max_tstamp FROM a
  JOIN b ON a.id = b.id
  GROUP BY a.id
```

Comment: But this query wouldn't return the entire row that containes the max(tstamp) for a.id. What I was trying to do was return the row that has the max(tstamp) for each a.id

Comment: MySQL's `JOIN` system is really casual and non-deterministic, but it can be coached into producing the right results. `ORDER BY b.tstamp` could group it up correctly.